# How to use decimal numer (Double data type) as placeholder in String resource

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

I want to use a more than 1 data type inside a placeholder within a String resource but whenever I try to use a demical number as a numerical value, an error is returned.

**Kotlin**

```
val currentLocale = Locale.getDefault()
val distanceWalked = 5.2
val numberFormatter: NumberFormat
val amountOut: String
numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(currentLocale)
amountOut = numberFormatter.format(distanceWalked)

tv.txt = getString(R.string.distance_decimalnumber_placeholder,amountOut,"*")
```

**Stirng resouce**

```
<string name="distance_decimalnumber_placeholder">You have walked %1$d%2$s metres</string>
```

**Expected result**

You have walked 5.2* metres

**Error**

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
>
> Wrong argument type for formatting argument '#1' in distance_decimalnumber_placeholder: conversion is 'd', received String (argument #2 in method call)

Comment: you aready converted to string at: ```amountOut = numberFormatter.format(distanceWalked)``` you need to replace with string now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mistake `d` is for ints

The problem:

You aready converted to string at: `amountOut = numberFormatter.format(distanceWalked)` you need to replace with string now

Solution: You don`t need to use `$f` you need to use `$s`

```
tv.txt = getString(R.string.distance_decimalnumber_placeholder,amountOut /* this is a string also*/ ,"*")
<string name="distance_decimalnumber_placeholder">You have walked %1$s%2$s metres</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention two things :

Don't use d for double ... d is treated as int so use f instead of d. So don't use this

```
 <string name="distance_decimalnumber_placeholder">You have walked %1$d%2$s metres</string>
```

And You don't need a chartype specifier to display * use * after the f like this

```
 <string name="distance_decimalnumber_placeholder">You have walked %1$f* metres</string>
```

Notice that I have added only one place holder.